# How is Laravel able to place facades in a global and custom namespace?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, facade

I've had this problem for a while, and it's really been bugging me, so I figured I'd ask. In Laravel, how are they able to allow access to facades with two namespaces? If you don't understand what I mean, here's an example.
Both of the following statements will work when using the session facade:

```
use Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

I've searched all over the web and I still have yet to find an answer for this problem.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-laravel-facades-work-and-how-to-use-them-elsewhere/ - facade aliases are in config/app.php, see link for more info on autoloader

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "config\app.php" file there is an aliases array which is used in Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader.
Then Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader calls **class_alias** method for making an alias in the global namespace. 
The actual flow is a little bit complicated because of lazy loading.